# How do I specify a TCP transport is server mode (listening) or client mode in activemq?

Tags: spring, message-queue, activemq-classic, apache-camel, apache-mina

The example given for a spring injected endpoint is as follows:

```
<endpoint id="hl7listener" uri="mina:tcp://localhost:8888?sync=true&amp;codec=hl7codec"/>
```

How do I setup a client mode endpoint such that is will connect to a specific port on another server?

How do I configure the endpoint to listen for inbound connections? (the example seems to be a listener as indicated by its descriptive id but why?)

Note: I am not actually using the HL7 protocol or codec. I will be developing my own for a proprietary protocol codec.

Answer (score 0):

was this answered on [the thread here](http://www.nabble.com/Usage-of-Mina-in-camelContext-for-TCP-loop.-td20348095s22882.html)?

Comment: dead link now - do you have an updated link